# Manually adding JavaScript libraries to WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

My WebStorm is running on a machine that has no internet access.  How can I add plugins & JavaScript libraries manually?

Answer (score 2):

- download the desired library using another machine (connected to internet)
- use the usb drive to copy it to your computer :)
- add this library using `Add..` button in `Settings/javaScript/Libraries`

Plugins can also be loaded from disk - `Settings/Plugins`, `Install plugin from disk`